# What's new in jQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What's new in jQuery(including UI) and will I have problems(using UI dialog and datepicker) when switch to 1.4(and 1.8.2) ?

Comment: That depends :) Which version are you on now, and which plugins are you using?  As a quick reference before I head out here, these are the 1.4 breaking changes: http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards

Comment: I use the previous versions and I use only jHtmlArea.

Comment: If you're only upgrading because of the `$.proxy()` in my answer, you could do it the long way instead, without needing 1.4: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6AMxm/1/

Comment: And yes ,and no.From the above link ,i saw that the jQuery 1.4 have better performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some breaking [changes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards). The most important point is to make sure that all plugins you are using has been already updated to the 1.4 support, and use the updated versions only. Then you shouldn't have any issues, or only minor issues that you can eventually easily solve. But the benefits (for example performance) are worth of it.

Answer (score 0):

I liked this one most:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    css: {
        fontWeight: 700,
        color: 'green'
    },
    click: function(){
        alert('Foo has been clicked!');
    }
});
```

You have a nice collection [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-1-4-released-the-15-new-features-you-must-know/) as well.